# Why ng e2e builds modules?

Tags: selenium, angular-cli

I used selenium webdriver before, in custom build project. It just opened web page of my project right away and immediately started running test cases. The only prerequisite was to start project server before launching it.

Now after creating generic project using 'ng new' I started it with 'ng serve'. Then I ran 'ng e2e' to test UI. It works, but for some reason it goes through whole module building thing again. It takes some time while I would like tests to start as fast as possible, and I know from my experience that it can be done.

The question: Can module building phase of ng e2e be omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with --no-serve option

```
ng e2e --no-serve
```

Comment: when I use this command it does not rebuild modules, but it cannot open project web page properly and test fails (

Comment: @eugenekr How do you build your project? After the build are you able to manually open your application at the url the build tells you (say, localhost:4200)?

Comment: Yes, after I issue ng serve, I can open the project at localhost:4200. Now I reinstalled ng-cli on new machine and ng e2e does not rebuild modules but gives me the getaddrinfo exception. I give up with this utility, thanks for trying to help me out though :)

Comment: Please discard my previous comment. getaddrinfo exception happened because I was disconnected from internet at the moment. Also, I have managed to get ng e2e --no-serve work - just needed to keep another cmd window running with ng serve, don't know how I missed it before )

Answer (score 2):

with the angular 6 and on --no-serve is not available anymore, so use instead:

```
ng e2e "--dev-server-target="
```

(yes empty value after the '=')
this will work if you have another window running an ng serve command.